# What is the best conceptual approach, in Rails, to managing content areas in what is otherwise a web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administration

(A while back I read this great post: http://aaronlongwell.com/2009/06/the-ruby-on-rails-cms-dilemma.html, discussing the "Rails CMS Dilemma".  It describes conceptual approaches to managing content in websites vs web apps.  I'm still a beginner with Rails, but had a bit of a PHP background, and I still have trouble wrapping my brain around this.

A lot of what I run into is customers who want a website that is not 100% website, and not 100% web app...  That is, perhaps there are several pages of business-to-public facing content, but then there are application elements, and the whole overall look is supposed to be cohesive.  This was always fairly simple in PHP, as you just kind of dropped your app code into the PHP "script", etc (though I know there are plenty of cons to this platform and approach).

So I am wondering, what is the best approach in Rails for doing this?

Say you have an application with user authentication and some sort of CRUD stuff going on, where users collaborate on projects or something.  Well, what is the optimal approach for managing the text/images of the "How This Site Works" and "Our Company" pages, which people may also want to view?  Is it just simply having a pages controller and several text fields, with an admin panel on the back end that lets you edit those fields?  Or is it perhaps a common approach to start off with something like Refinery, and then build on top of it for the non-content-driven areas of a site?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  It's just that I've read Hartl's book and others, and they never address this practical low-level stuff for a beginner...  Sure, I can build a Twitter feed now, but what Twitter's "About" page (http://twitter.com/about)?  I can't just throw text into a view and give that to a client... They want a super easy way to see the site tree, edit content areas, AND administrate/run their Twitter feed or whatever.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a CMS that runs as a plugin in your Rails application. If that's the case, I'd suggest that you try http://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa

Comment: This is pretty cool... However, I'm not sure it suits exactly what I'm going for...  In the end, this is still a CMS for pages that are completely content-oriented.  What I'm getting at, is how does the user/admin (client) change a blurb of text, or a menu item, that happens to be inside single and/or multiple pages of a web app?  I guess in many situations the team would just edit the view file.  But what if you want to build all of this into an admin panel?  What's the best approach?  What's the db design?

Comment: hey.. that CMS (see link above) has something called "snippets". A snippet is pretty much any text/html that you can embed in your web app using the snippet slug. It comes with a helper function that you can use in your application views: `<%= cms_snippet_content(:my_blurb) %>`. It can also replace your controller's views making them editable by your client! See "Integrating CMS with your app" in the docs.